# C++ sending vector object between client and server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop

I'm fairly new to c++ and have never worked with vectors or server/clients before.
I currently have a client and server that can send char messages from one to the other. but one problem is that it just can send individual words across. So if it sees a space it put the next thing on a new line. What i need is to be able to send my objects to the client. without any weird spacing issues

i have a vector which contains some objects for example i have one called:

`vector<Employees> Staff;`
which also has a print method:

```
void printVector(const vector<Employees>&);
```

My question is how can i send this vector or use this printVector method to show/print/cout on both the server and client (through sending it somehow).

Here is a segment from my server.cpp file

```
if (sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
        {
            cout << "Connection received!" << endl << endl << "Sending File" << endl << endl;
            for (;; Sleep(10))
            {   
                char* message = new char[256];
                ZeroMemory(message, 256);
                cin >> message;
                getchar();
                send(sConnect, message, 256, NULL);                     
            }                   
    }
    return 0;
```

Here is a segment from my client.cpp file

```
if (confirm == "Y" )
    {
        connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        cout << "Connected!" << endl << "" << endl;
        char* message = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(message, sizeof(message));
        for (;; Sleep(50))
        {
            if (recv(sConnect, message, 256, NULL))
            {
                cout << message;
                ZeroMemory(message, 256);
                cout << endl;

            }
        } 

    } else {
        cout << "You did not say yes or an error has occured" << endl << "Closing connection" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
```

All help appreciated :)

Comment: You have many memory leaks. If you know how to use vector, avoid raw pointers and just use vector

Comment: Serialisation is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Leigh, do you have skype? If so add me, and i'll help you out. I have a feeling you watched the same youtube tutorials I did on server/client, and they're awful. They don't even help you understand how it works.

Add me on skype : Jmoneyswaghoes
if you want help on understanding how servers/clients work and how to get your program working how you'd like.